# Inheritance objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, inheritance, methods, properties

Can anyone explain me how inheritance works under the hood in Objective-C ?

Lets say I have class B which inheritance class A. What is the glue between those two clases so class B to be able to access properties  and methods of class A ?

Comment: What do mean with "glue"? And do you have a good understanding of object-orientation/inheritance per se? That is, have you already worked with another object oriented language?

Comment: Regarding messages, the docs explain it well here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtHowMessagingWorks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH104-TPXREF134

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isa`.

The `isa` identifies the type at runtime, and refers to its dynamic 'glue' (see [vtable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vtable)). Because of `isa`, the runtime knows (or is able to determine) which methods to perform when a message is sent, as well as the type of `self`.

When an instance is created, its `isa` is assigned.

The other primary contributor is, of course, the compiler, which takes over when you get down to the lower levels -- e.g. accessing instance variables directly and defining methods. There are a number of calls the compiler adds when creating objects and when messaging.

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand following code

```
@interface SampleViewController : UIViewController{}
```

This specifies the fact that SampleViewController inherits UIViewController and you can access all properties/methods of UIViewController.

I agree with what Justin said about dynamic 'glue'.